# Why does very simple port of the official Keras mnist example to tensorflow 2.x result in massive drop in accuracy?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, mnist, tf.keras

Here is the mnist example from the Keras documentation:
https://keras.io/examples/mnist_cnn/

I put it into google colab, under Tensorflow 1.x, and it performs really well:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15NW-lXhRUxqSCCygVxddXCo5ID7yF2iL

I made very simple changes to make it execute under TF-2.x:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ul-eFn1XRe9ta3cu5vHchaa4DxStRda_

It completely crushes performance!  Accuracy drops like a rock!

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the optimizers. `tf.keras.optimizers.Adadelta` uses a learning rate of 0.001. `keras.optimizers.Adadelta` uses a learning rate of 1.0.

Check [keras.optimizers](https://keras.io/optimizers/) and [tf.keras.optimizers.Adadelta](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Adadelta) for more details. In particular, the Tensorflow page mentions that Adadelta is supposed to have a learning rate of 1.0 to match the original paper.

Comment: Susmit, I really appreciate that.  It works beautifully.

Comment: Happy to help! :)